# Enter key as well as submit button on Google Script Code in Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I would like to be able to use enter as well as the submit button to execute / accept data entry and commit to cell.

I cannot seem to get the code to work.
Any advice how to modify?

```
      <script>
         var itemBox = document.getElementById("itemname");
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);
        function addRecord(){

          var name = itemBox.value;
          if(name.trim().length == 0){
             M.toast({html: "Please enter a valid barcode!"})
          } else{

          var data = {
            name:itemBox.value
          };
          google.script.run.appendData(data);
          itemBox.value = "";
        }
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide detailed information about `I cannot seem to get the code to work.`? And, can you provide your Google Apps Script?

Comment: Please provide more information about what have you alredy tried and what was the exact issue with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please read comments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<script>
  var itemBox = document.getElementById("itemname");
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);
  function addRecord(){
    var name = itemBox.value;//item box is undefined
    if(name.trim().length == 0){
      M.toast({html: "Please enter a valid barcode!"})//M is undefined and toast does not exist clientside
    } else{
      var data = {name:itemBox.value};
      google.script.run.appendData(data);
        itemBox.value = "";
    }
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Spreadsheet.toast() is a server side method of Class Spreadsheet and is not intended to function clientside on the browser.

[Spreadsheet.toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String))

So far your description of your question is incomplete

Comment: `itemBox` is defined on the first line. `M` is `undefined`, but it's a probably reference to [tag:Materialize]

Comment: duh how did I miss that